# Php executes with different results in command line than when browsed to in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, ldap, centos7

I setup a CentOS 7 vm webserver with the LAMP stack. Over the last few days I have been trying to get an LDAPS connection working to my Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller.

I have been able to connect to my DC with: `ldapsearch -H "ldaps://server.ad.com" -D "domain\user-name" -W` for a couple days. I am also able to use the `openssl s_client -connect server.ad.com -prexit` command to verify the SSL cert (as I am using a self-signed cert).

However, whenever I browse to my PHP webpage in the /var/www/html/test/index.php I always receive "Can't contact LDAP server" errors when trying to `ldap_bind()`. Yesterday I tried running the PHP file from command line: `php /var/www/html/test/index.php` and found that my PHP ldap_bind() works every time when using the command line.

Searching on the internet, I have found that often the PHP-CLI and PHP Apache will use different php.ini files, but running the `php --ini` command only shows me a single php.ini file located in /etc/php.ini.

I am trying to figure out why PHP executes correctly from the command line but not when browsed to/run through Apache. Any info/ideas to help solve this would be greatly appreciated, thank-you!

Comment: I'm not entire sure how running `ldapsearch` and/or `openssl sclient` from the command line would be a good analog for what happens in PHP, but I could be wrong.. In any event, it might have something to do with the user executing the code (you vs <InsertWebServerUserHere>). Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: @GregL I guess the reason why I was using ldapsearch and openssl was to confirm that the ldaps:// and self signed certificates were correct, before trying to get the php working. Also if you use the -d 1 argument with ldapsearch, you can see the strace where ldap functions are called.... so I was verifying that the bind was happening. I have only been using linux ~4 days, so this is all really new to me. I like your idea about the users browsing to the webpage vs running php as root from the cli. As far as SELinux goes, I am not sure what this is and will have to look it up.

Comment: Probably more than you care to read, but [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts) article is probably a good place to start if you want to know about SELinux.

Comment: @GregL thanks, I was just reading the centos wiki page regarding it. Yes, SELinux is enabled.

Comment: Is `ldap_bind()` only throwing a 'Can't contact LDAP server' error? What about `ldap_connect()`?

Comment: @GregL ldap_connect() is successful. "Error code: 0 Error Message: success". ldap_bind() is only throwing a "Can't contact LDAP server" error. I tried to get additional error info using "LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE", but there is none. (as per the first comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)

Comment: I would be inclined to see if it works without SELinux enabled and go from there.

Comment: @GregL With SELinux disabled, the php ldap_bind() is now working as expected from a browser. I will continue reading the linked article and figure out how to setup Apache correctly while leaving SELinux enabled. Thank-you for the information on SELinux, I have been bashing my head against this for days... Please post an answer so that I can select your response! Cheers!

Comment: I suspect that SELinux and Apache are working right, but just need to be tweaked for your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works from the command-line but not via Apache, then it's one of a few things.

1. The user running the code (you vs apache)
2. SELinux is getting in the way

I guess they're sort of inter-related, but I'd suggest trying the pages with SELinux disabled and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

As GregL said, this is `SELinux` related, I had the same problem today and I didn't remember that `SELinux` was enabled.

```
[root@centos7 ~]# getsebool -a | grep http | grep ldap
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
```

So, if you do not want to disable SELinux globally, authorize it

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on
```

Perhaps you will need other things to enable (remote database access, ...), check with

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```